# Ограничения Foreign Key в админке Django

Tags: django, django-admin

У меня есть модели джанго:Продукт, Цвет, Категория

Продукт и Цвет имеют поля, зависимые от Категории.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в админке при редакте/добавлении после выбранной категории Продукта, в выпадающем списке цветов отображались только те цвета, которые относятся к этой категории. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Подменить queryset в нужном form field https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179129

Comment: Да, это я уже видел. Но как мне получать категорию, которая записана в другом поле, но еще не сохранена?

Comment: А вот это уже сильно сложнее, для обновления списка на лету придётся городить какой-нибудь ajax

Comment: Вот и возникает вопрос, как его прикрутить к админке. Либо может есть какое-то более рациональное решение этой задачи?